# dynamically addressing xml document fields

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am using a Visual basic application to generate and manage data which at the same time will be loaded into a webpage.

I have chosen to do this through XML as it seemed to be the path of least resistance.

This is not a standard xml file, pretty much each element has a unique name which can be referenced by both the vb app and the webpage to make sure that data can be correctly identified in both cases. however due to the complexity of the data I need to be able to reference the fields dynamically

**example**

textbox controls each have unique names which correspond to the xml element that they will load data to

```
Textbox Name = xml.<root>.<Name>
Textbox Age = xml.<root>.<Age>
Textbox Height = xml.<root>.<Height>
```

the idea is that the update function will be the same for all textboxes and will identify the xml element according to the name of the control that was updated:

```
xml.<root>. & Control.name = control.value
```

but I'm not quite able to work out if anything similar to this is possible.

Comment: I suggest you put the XPATH address of each node into the corresponding control's `.Tag` property.

Comment: I thought about this but I would still have the same issue where I am trying to reference the xml element using a string

Answer (score 0):

You have to use BindingSource to bind the data from your XML to controls as shown below.

Look into the below code, comments will explain the content

**Input:**

```
<root>
    <Name>Kumar Kumar</Name>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <Height>6</Height>
 </root>
```

**Code:**

```
       'DECLARE A BINDING SOURCE
        Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()

        'DECALRE DATASET TO READ XML
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

        'LOAD THE DATASET WITH XML
        ds.ReadXml("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\test\\test.xml")

        'BIND THE DATASET TO BINDINGSOURCE WHICH HAS LOADED XML
        bs.DataSource = ds
        bs.DataMember = ds.Tables(0).TableName

        'THIS IS IMPORTANT TO BIND THE CONTROLS TO MEMEBERS OF BINDING SOURCE
        'THE FIRST PARAMETER OF THE ADD, IS THE "TEXT" ATTRIBUTE OF TEXT BLOCK
        'SECOND PARAMETER OF THE ADD, IS BINDING SOURCE
        'THIRD PARAMETER IS THE XML ATTRIBUTE TO BE BOUND
        TextBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Name")
        TextBoxAge.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Age")
        TextBoxHeight.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Height")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I thought I would add the solution I ended up using in this case. I am aware that this is not a deployable solution, but in my specific case this has worked perfectly.

Basically, every `div` that contains info to be updated from the XML has its own ID and then the corresponding tag in the XML also has the same name as the id of the `div`. Then the JS code is as follows.

```
// read xml file into XMLDoc //get html elements bytagname "div" and
// then for loop through all of them
if (TableCells[i].id != "") {   
    xDataInput = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(TableCells[i].id);
    if (xDataInput[0].innerHTML == "True") {
       TableCells[i].className = "Active";
    }
}
```

Once again, this only works if all XML fields have unique names. Also any `div` tags that do not get data from the XML will have to have no id, or you will need to find a way to handle them within the `for` loop.